# How to get gmail thread id using JavaMail API in android?

Tags: smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-imap

As per **gimap documentation**  [*javamail new gimap doc*](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/package-summary.html), ImapMessage not casting to GmailMessage.

Doc code is:

`GmailMessage gmsg = (GmailMessage)msg; System.out.println("Gmail message ID is " + gmsg.getMsgId()); String[] labels = gmsg.getLabels(); for (String s : labels) System.out.println("Gmail message label: " + s);`

here msg is a object of ImapMessage.

***Error is:*** java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage cannot be cast to com.sun.mail.gimap.mailMessage

How to solve it?

My Imap connection code is:

```
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.Folder;

String IMAP_PROTOCOL = "imap";
String IMAP_HOST = "imap.gmail.com";
String IMAP_PORT = "993";

private Store store;
private Folder folderInbox;
private Session session;


  private Properties getServerProperties(String protocol, String host,
                                       String port) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    // server setting
    properties.put(String.format("mail.%s.host", protocol), host);
    properties.put(String.format("mail.%s.port", protocol), port);

    // SSL setting
    properties.setProperty(
            String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.class", protocol),
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty(
            String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.fallback", protocol),
            "false");
    properties.setProperty(
            String.format("mail.%s.socketFactory.port", protocol),
            String.valueOf(port));

    return properties;
  }


//Now connect gmail with imap
Properties properties = getServerProperties(protocol, host, port);

session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

store = session.getStore(protocol);
store.connect(userName, password);

// opens the inbox folder
folderInbox = store.getFolder(folderName);
folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

// fetches new messages from server
Message[] messages = folderInbox.getMessages();

     for (Message msg: messages
             ) {

      GmailMessage gmsg = (GmailMessage)msg;
      System.out.println("Gmail message ID is " + gmsg.getMsgId());
      String[] labels = gmsg.getLabels();
      for (String s : labels)
            System.out.println("Gmail message label: " + s);
            
        }
```

Comment: Are you using the Gmail Provider?  What’s your set up code?

Comment: It looks like the gmail provider uses the “gimap” protocol to select it.  If you use imap, you only get the generic imap provider.